# ASP.Net Core 2 - How can I get Visual Studio Code to detect Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, razor-pages

In Asp.net core 2, they introduced razor pages. Using visual studio code if I create a 'Pages' folder in the root of the solution and then add a new item 'Greeting.cshtml', then add an @page directive at the top followed by the content I want to display, I don't see anything when I navigate to http://localhost.whateverport#/Greeting after running.

If I did the same thing in VS17 it works.

So my question is, how can I get Visual Studio code to detect that this is a razor page?

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code that enables or disables this functionality; it is simply not their responsibility. If you have a project in VS where it works, and a project in VS Code where it does not work, then there will be some other *relevant* differences that cause this. – Without seeing anything about your projects, it’s impossible to help you there though.

Comment: I actually just ran into what I think is the same problem. When creating a page in VS the code generated behind the scenes appears in the directory tree, and in VSCode it doesn't, which makes it pretty hard to develop a Razor page.

Answer (score 2):

Use dotnet new page command to add razor page. For example

`dotnet new page -n Index -na MyProject.Pages -o Pages`

This will create index.cshtml and index.cshtml.cs file under pages folder.

Run help command `dotnet new page -h` to view the options. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: How to launch it? Hitting F5 opens up browser pointing to non-existing index.html.